# Jsoup returning cached data (server side most probably)

Tags: android, jsoup

So, I am using jsoup.connect(url).get() to get live data from a website. The problem is I did this multiple times and now the data being retrieved is old, whereas, browsing from my regular mobile chrome browser shows me latest data. I have cleared the application data and so this looks more like a server side caching (?). How can I override this to get new data everytime?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: I have tried changing get() to post() and used an additional &fetch=randomnumberhere in the link to randomize a new string each time so the server gets fooled. Tomorrow morning I will see if it works, though from what I understand only post should also work alone.